# Reinstate an account via Yodlee that was removed with removeItemAccount

Tags: yodlee

I can't see the process to follow in the Yodlee docs for re-adding an account after it has been removed. I'm using the REST API. The situation is as follows:

1. User adds a site account
2. All the user's accounts at that site are added and aggregated
3. User removes a single account with removeItemAccount
4. User now wishes to re-add this account

There doesn't seem to be an API endpoint for re-adding this account. Because it is deleted it doesn't even show up in any of the other site-level calls such as getItemSummariesForSite or startSiteRefresh

What is the process I should be following to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To re-add add an account which has been deleted from a site account, user needs to add the same site account again but selecting the same site and providing the credentials again. This will just refresh the already added accounts under that site and re-add the one which was deleted. But the old data of the deleted account will not be present as it will be added again as a fresh data.

Comment: Hi, Even after using this API to delete a bank account from Yodlee, transactions from Old account is still visible available in the aggregation API call. Any clues where am I being wrong?